# How does Facebook figure out my top friends

Tags: facebook, chat, friends, profile

The friends in my chat window on Facebook are pretty much all people I interact with most on Facebook.  There is one person however that I have removed from my newsfeed and though I used Facebook to chat with him a couple of years ago, I don't talk to him anymore.  Why does he still show up as a top friend? He never likes any posts or photos- we really don't communicate at all.  What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a list of your top friends. It's really more of a mix of

- interacted recently
- interacted frequently over a short period of time
- interacted most